# Wordpress Installed through cpanel not working

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I have installed a WordPress app to a domain in Cpanel. After installing when I click on the link they provided (both wp-admin and site) I get an error like

```
Requested Page Not Found
Error Code:500
```

Can anyone help me clear this?
Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please make ensure you have a correct system configuration

Visit https://wordpress.org/support/article/requirements/

and correct file & folder permission on sever.

Comment: Actually, my company has installed 4 applications before this and all of them working fine. This is the first time I'm using Cpanel for WordPress.

Comment: The same WordPress installed on 4 application or different platform.?

Comment: You can also check your .htaccess and php.ini check upload_limit, max_execution_time are proper set.

Comment: I  used the customer service and they made it. Thank you all for your response

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Domain Name Server, also try to change PHP versions.